# problem with multiple references foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys

i have 4 tables :

**1 - tbl_cars**

```
id (PK)
car_name
model
year
```

**2 - tbl_carOwner**

```
id (PK)
carId (FK - reference to tbl_cars)
ownerId (FK - reference to tbl_ownerPersnoal or tbl_ownerCompany or tbl_ownerGov) 
ownerType (to make a differentiation about owner)
```

**3 - tbl_ownerPersonal**

```
id (PK)
name
ic_no
address
```

**4 - tbl_ownerCompany**

```
id (PK)
registration_no
business_type
name
address
fax
mail
```

**5 - tbl_ownerGov**

```
id (PK)
agency_name
```

As you can see, I need to make a differentiation between owner because of the different field.

How can I relate all the table with mysql and nhibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this - it's against the basic principles of relational database design. A foreign key can only ever reference one and only one table - you cannot have a foreign key that references one of three tables...

What you need to do is have three FK keys in your `tbl_carOwner`

```
ownerIdPersonal  (FK to tbl_ownerPersonal)
ownerIdCompany   (FK to tbl_ownerCompany)
ownerIdGov       (FK to tbl_ownerGov)
```

and preferably make sure only exactly one of those keys if valid (NOT NULL) at any given time.